# JSON loading from the text file

Tags: python

I'm trying to test this code out: https://github.com/shanepm/500px-Bot/blob/master/500px.py

Completely new to Phyton, but have programming skills.
Running on Windows 10.

I get this error msg:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The error is pointed to be at `pendingFollowList = json.loads(f.read())` and on the rest of the `json.loads`...calls

Have tried to pass one more argument on the line above:

```
with open('pendingUsers.txt', 'r', **encoding='utf-8'**) as f:
```

This did not help.

Have also checked Encoding on .txt files as well.

Anybody that knows what to do??

Thanks in advance!
Alen

Comment: Could we see your JSON code?  It looks like the error comes from there.

Comment: This is hard to say without looking at the json it self, can you try `json.load(f)` instead, see if that loads the json without causing an issue?

Comment: Also maybe change your json file name from `pendingUsers.txt` to `pendingUsers.json`

Comment: Link to the file is in the description. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Link to the code is in the description of my issue

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is instead of using a .txt file, use a .json file because you're using json. I've used

```
import json

with open("filename.json") as f:
    Json_content = json.load(f)
```

And then if you want to access one of the values of your Json you would `Json_content["key_in_json_file"]`

Comment: Hi!
When I try your little example, I get the same error. Come across one web page where they say that this can be Win 10 specific issue...

Comment: @AlenĆemer is your json formatted properly? I would use an online checked off some kind

Answer (score 0):

all!

It helped out to change the extension.
My main issue was that my input files where blank and not json-formatted correctly.

Thanks to all for the contribution.

BR
Alen